# How to get Consumer Key and Consumer Secret of Connected App in Apex?

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps

In a managed package we have a Connected app, which will be connected to the central server from all of the Orgs which have installed the package. In the post-installation script, we need to send the consumer key and consumer secret to the central server, so that the server can have access to all the of the Orgs.

Please suggest if you have a better approach for this.